# Error with Xception Transfer Learning Model

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, transfer-learning

My Dataset has 2 folder Test and Train, Test contains 2 folders inside with Covid X rays and Normal X rays and same is with the Train folder. Im getting 99.4% accuracy on val_set on last epoch of training, but while plotting confusion matrix, i am getting not even 60% accuracy. Stuck badly, PLEASE HELP! and also my Y_pred looks weird, and not between 0-1 certainity, i need help to get the same 99.4% results on my confusion matrix and classification report.

```
import os
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import keras
from keras.applications import xception
from keras.layers import *
from keras.models import *
from keras.preprocessing import image

model = xception.Xception(weights='imagenet', include_top=False, input_shape=(224, 224, 3))
for layers in model.layers:
    layers.trainable=False
    
flat1 = Flatten()(model.layers[-1].output)
class1 = Dense(256, activation='relu')(flat1)
output = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(class1)

model = Model(inputs = model.inputs, outputs = output)


model.compile(loss = 'binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])


train_datagen = image.ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale = 1./255,
    shear_range = 0.2,
    zoom_range = 0.2,
    horizontal_flip = True,
    )

test_datagen = image.ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255)

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    '/Users/xd_anshul/Desktop/Research/Major/CovidDataset/Train',
    target_size = (224,224),
    batch_size = 10,
    class_mode='binary')

validation_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    '/Users/xd_anshul/Desktop/Research/Major/CovidDataset/Test',
    target_size = (224,224),
    batch_size = 10,
    class_mode='binary')

#model Fitting

hist = model.fit(
    train_generator,
    epochs=2,
    validation_data=validation_generator)



from sklearn.metrics import classification_report, confusion_matrix

Y_pred = model.predict_generator(validation_generator, steps = np.ceil(validation_generator.samples / validation_generator.batch_size), verbose=1, workers=0)
y_pred = [np.where(predictions>0.5, 1, 0) for predictions in Y_pred]
print('Confusion Matrix')
print(confusion_matrix(validation_generator.classes, y_pred))
print('Classification Report')
target_names = ['Covid', 'Normal']
print(classification_report(validation_generator.classes, y_pred, target_names=target_names))

OUTPUT::

Epoch 1/2
255/255 [==============================] - 464s 2s/step - loss: 1.4076 - accuracy: 0.9342 - val_loss: 0.3753 - val_accuracy: 0.9718
Epoch 2/2
255/255 [==============================] - 558s 2s/step - loss: 0.1218 - accuracy: 0.9885 - val_loss: 0.0181 - val_accuracy: 0.9944
Confusion Matrix
[[310 100]
 [ 97  25]]
Classification Report
              precision    recall  f1-score   support

       Covid       0.76      0.76      0.76       410
      Normal       0.20      0.20      0.20       122

    accuracy                           0.63       532
   macro avg       0.48      0.48      0.48       532
weighted avg       0.63      0.63      0.63       532

Y_pred looks like:

1.05698e-14
2.25061e-13
3.96925e-19
5.53114e-17
3.4461e-32
1.2413e-32
2.29092e-28
4.01138e-17
3.81177e-23
1.88817e-07
1.164e-07
.
.
.
(532 Values)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after code

```
output = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(class1)
```

put in this code

```
model=Model(inputs=model.input, outputs=output)
```

In your validation generator you did not specify a target size so add

```
target_size=(224,224)
```

Also note you have a batch size of 10 in your train_generator. In model.fit you have steps_per_epoch=9. That implies you are only using 90 training images per epoch.
How many training images do you have? Also you  did not specify a batch_size for the validation generator so it defaults to 32. You set validation steps to 2 in model.fit so you will go through 64 validation images per epoch. How many validation images do you have?

Comment: Thanks so much, I have around 5000 images in Training and 500 validation, what should be the batch size and Steps? Also, I have a Mac Air and its really slow, could you please help me with the solution?

Comment: Batch size is usually constrained by available memory. Try 32 for starters. Then steps is usually samples//batch_size. In model.fit you can leave them as None and it will determine the steps internally. Join Kaggle or Google Colab. You can use their GPU's on line free of charge.

Comment: Hi Gerry, Im facing problems on the above code, I think i have problems setting steps, batch_size and other hyperparameters. I am getting 95% accuracy on Val_set but when plotting confusion matrix, out of 532 test images, only 410 predicted correctly after training the model, Could you please help me? Thanking you in Advance!

Comment: so I assume you are using the trained model to make predictions on the validation set is that correct? Please show the code for how you make the predictions and the way you create the confusion matrix. If you are predicting on the validation set you should get the same accuracy as you got on the validation set for the last epoch of training. Try running model.evaluate on the validation set.

Comment: Hi, Gerry Please see the updated question with the edited code, I am getting very bad results on the confusion matrix but while training 99.44% accuracy on val_set on the last epoch.

Comment: Gerry, so what should be the appropriate line of code instead of "y_pred = [np.where(predictions>0.5, 1, 0) for predictions in Y_pred]" ?

Comment: To get the same 99.44% accuracy on confusion matrix?

Comment: your problem is with y_pred = [np.where(predictions>0.5, 1, 0) for predictions in Y_pred]. print this out and you will see it is a list of arrays because Y_pred is an array try  y_pred=[ np.argmax(Y_pred[i]) for i in range(val_generator.samples)]